# Secondary axis with twinx(): how to add to legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, axis, twinx

I have a plot with two y-axes, using `twinx()`. I also give labels to the lines, and want to show them with `legend()`, but I only succeed to get the labels of one axis in the legend:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc('mathtext', default='regular')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(time, Swdown, '-', label = 'Swdown')
ax.plot(time, Rn, '-', label = 'Rn')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(time, temp, '-r', label = 'temp')
ax.legend(loc=0)
ax.grid()
ax.set_xlabel("Time (h)")
ax.set_ylabel(r"Radiation ($MJ\,m^{-2}\,d^{-1}$)")
ax2.set_ylabel(r"Temperature ($^\circ$C)")
ax2.set_ylim(0, 35)
ax.set_ylim(-20,100)
plt.show()
```

So I only get the labels of the first axis in the legend, and not the label 'temp' of the second axis. How could I add this third label to the legend?

[image]

Comment: [*Don't do this in anywhere remotely close to any production code*] When my only aim is to generate a beautiful plot with the appropiate legend ASAP, I use an ugly hack of plotting an empty array on `ax` with the style I use on `ax2`: in your case, `ax.plot([], [], '-r', label = 'temp')`. It's much faster and simpler than doing it properly...

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57484812/3642162 for pandas and twinx

Comment: The legend will be merged properly if you comment out the line `ax.legend(loc=0)`. A simple and natural alternative that preserves the default merged legend without having to tweak is to replace that line with `fig.legend(loc=0)` instead.  As explained in the answer by
@ImportanceOfBeingErnest below, the legend with multiple axes belong to the figure `fig`, rather than to the left axis `ax`. In retrospect, it should be obvious that `ax.legend()` will mess things up. (I don't have your data to check your particular case, but this is what I've observed on other data)

Comment: In case you use subplots, check out the answer by Suuuehgi below, it's the most elegant to me.

Answer (score 574, accepted):

You can easily add a second legend by adding the line:

```
ax2.legend(loc=0)
```

You'll get this:

[image]

But if you want all labels on one legend then you should do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc('mathtext', default='regular')

time = np.arange(10)
temp = np.random.random(10)*30
Swdown = np.random.random(10)*100-10
Rn = np.random.random(10)*100-10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

lns1 = ax.plot(time, Swdown, '-', label = 'Swdown')
lns2 = ax.plot(time, Rn, '-', label = 'Rn')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
lns3 = ax2.plot(time, temp, '-r', label = 'temp')

# added these three lines
lns = lns1+lns2+lns3
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
ax.legend(lns, labs, loc=0)

ax.grid()
ax.set_xlabel("Time (h)")
ax.set_ylabel(r"Radiation ($MJ\,m^{-2}\,d^{-1}$)")
ax2.set_ylabel(r"Temperature ($^\circ$C)")
ax2.set_ylim(0, 35)
ax.set_ylim(-20,100)
plt.show()
```

Which will give you this:

[image]

Comment: This fails with `errorbar` plots. For a solution that correctly handles them, see below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10129461/1319447

Comment: To prevent two overlapping legends as in my case where I specifed two .legend(loc=0), you should specify two different values for the legend location value (both other than 0). See: http://matplotlib.org/api/legend_api.html

Comment: I had some trouble adding a single line to some subplot with multiple lines `ax1`. In this case use `lns1=ax1.lines` and then append `lns2` to this list.

Comment: The different values used by `loc` are explained [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend)

Comment: See the answer below for a more automatic way (with matplotlib >= 2.1): https://stackoverflow.com/a/47370214/653364

Comment: How do you line up the tick marks for both y axis? In the above example, the '0' on the left yticklabels should be in line with '5' on the right yticklabels, etc. How to adjust it? `matplotlib` is so painful for beginners. :(

Comment: Could you tell me in the `ax.ylabel` value, why is there two `\,` in the label? I tried to remove it and display the results, it looks the same to me.

Comment: Doing that works better:
    lines, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
    lines2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
    lines3, labels3 = ax3.get_legend_handles_labels()
    ax3.legend(lines + lines2 + lines3, labels + labels2 + labels3)

Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10129461/7115301

Comment: There's a good answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344063/single-legend-for-multiple-axes/41030990

Comment: This method works if you plots are similar. In my case I had one line plot and one scatter and @zgana answer worked for me

Comment: Doesn't work for scatter either

Answer (score 307):

I'm not sure if this functionality is new, but you can also use the get_legend_handles_labels() method rather than keeping track of lines and labels yourself:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc('mathtext', default='regular')

pi = np.pi

# fake data
time = np.linspace (0, 25, 50)
temp = 50 / np.sqrt (2 * pi * 3**2) \
        * np.exp (-((time - 13)**2 / (3**2))**2) + 15
Swdown = 400 / np.sqrt (2 * pi * 3**2) * np.exp (-((time - 13)**2 / (3**2))**2)
Rn = Swdown - 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(time, Swdown, '-', label = 'Swdown')
ax.plot(time, Rn, '-', label = 'Rn')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(time, temp, '-r', label = 'temp')

# ask matplotlib for the plotted objects and their labels
lines, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
lines2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax2.legend(lines + lines2, labels + labels2, loc=0)

ax.grid()
ax.set_xlabel("Time (h)")
ax.set_ylabel(r"Radiation ($MJ\,m^{-2}\,d^{-1}$)")
ax2.set_ylabel(r"Temperature ($^\circ$C)")
ax2.set_ylim(0, 35)
ax.set_ylim(-20,100)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is the only solution that can handle axes where the plots overlap with the legends (the last axes is the one that should plot the legends)

Comment: This solution also works with `errorbar` plots, while the accepted one fails (showing a line and its errorbars separately, and none of them with the right label). Plus, it's simpler.

Comment: slight catch: it doesn't work if you want to overwrite the label for `ax2` and it doesn't have one set from the start

Comment: Remark: For classic plots, you don't need to specify the label argument. But for others, eg. bars you need to.

Comment: This also makes everything much easier if you dont know beforehand how many lines are going to be plotted.

Comment: This is much easier to implement than all other answers.

Answer (score 180):

From matplotlib version 2.1 onwards, you may use a **figure legend**. Instead of `ax.legend()`, which produces a legend with the handles from the axes `ax`, one can create a figure legend

```
fig.legend(loc="upper right")
```

which will gather all handles from all subplots in the figure. Since it is a figure legend, it will be placed at the corner of the figure, and the `loc` argument is relative to the figure.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,10)
y = np.linspace(0,10)
z = np.sin(x/3)**2*98

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y, '-', label = 'Quantity 1')

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(x,z, '-r', label = 'Quantity 2')
fig.legend(loc="upper right")

ax.set_xlabel("x [units]")
ax.set_ylabel(r"Quantity 1")
ax2.set_ylabel(r"Quantity 2")

plt.show()
```

[image]

In order to place the legend back into the axes, one would supply a `bbox_to_anchor` and a `bbox_transform`. The latter would be the axes transform of the axes the legend should reside in. The former may be the coordinates of the edge defined by `loc` given in axes coordinates.

```
fig.legend(loc="upper right", bbox_to_anchor=(1,1), bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)
```

[image]

Comment: So, version 2.1 already released? But in Anaconda 3, I tried `conda upgrade matplotlib` no newer versions found, I'm still using v.2.0.2

Comment: This does not seem to work when you have many subplots. It adds a single legend for all subplots.
One typically needs one legend for each subplot, containing series in both primary and secondary axes in each legend.

Comment: @sancho Correct, that's what is written in the third sentence of this answer, "...which will gather all handles from all subplots in the figure.".

Comment: While the gathered legends works for twin y-axes, it seems when using seaborn the legends from each of the two axes still show up on the plot.  The code described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54782540/8508004), along with the addition in the comment by Mihai Cherlau to hide  those. For the example above you'd use `ax.legend_.remove();ax2.legend_.remove()`.

Comment: Excellent answer. In my case I needed `fig.legend(loc="upper right"); ax.get_legend().remove()`, otherwise two legends were printed. Go figure. :-)

Comment: This is the best answer, and appreciated. But even *more* pythonic would be if the api worked as expected: `plt.legend()` just working as usual for all labels, and then let people manipulate labels for each axis individually using (something like) `ax.legend()`, in the rare case they would want to do that.

Comment: This works with one subplot (and in this case this is a better solution than the other). With multiple subplots there is a single legend, which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 57):

You can easily get what you want by adding the line in ax:

```
ax.plot([], [], '-r', label = 'temp')
```

or

```
ax.plot(np.nan, '-r', label = 'temp')
```

This would plot nothing but add a label to legend of ax.

I think this is a much easier way.
It's not necessary to track lines automatically when you have only a few lines in the second axes, as fixing by hand like above would be quite easy. Anyway, it depends on what you need.

The whole code is as below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc('mathtext', default='regular')

time = np.arange(22.)
temp = 20*np.random.rand(22)
Swdown = 10*np.random.randn(22)+40
Rn = 40*np.random.rand(22)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax.twinx()

#---------- look at below -----------

ax.plot(time, Swdown, '-', label = 'Swdown')
ax.plot(time, Rn, '-', label = 'Rn')

ax2.plot(time, temp, '-r')  # The true line in ax2
ax.plot(np.nan, '-r', label = 'temp')  # Make an agent in ax

ax.legend(loc=0)

#---------------done-----------------

ax.grid()
ax.set_xlabel("Time (h)")
ax.set_ylabel(r"Radiation ($MJ\,m^{-2}\,d^{-1}$)")
ax2.set_ylabel(r"Temperature ($^\circ$C)")
ax2.set_ylim(0, 35)
ax.set_ylim(-20,100)
plt.show()
```

The plot is as below:

[image]

---

Update: add a better version:

```
ax.plot(np.nan, '-r', label = 'temp')
```

This will do nothing while `plot(0, 0)` may change the axis range.

---

One extra example for scatter

```
ax.scatter([], [], s=100, label = 'temp')  # Make an agent in ax
ax2.scatter(time, temp, s=10)  # The true scatter in ax2

ax.legend(loc=1, framealpha=1)
```

Comment: I like this. Its kind of ugly in the way it "tricks" the system, but so simple to implement.

Comment: This is really simple to implement. But when using this with scatter, the resulting scatter size in the legend is just a tiny point.

Comment: @greeeeeeen Then you just should specify the marker size when making the scatter plot :-)

Comment: @SyrtisMajor I, of course, tried that. But that didn't change the marker size in the legend.

Comment: @greeeeeeen Have you changed the marker size of the agent scatter? See my post, I added a snippet of example code.

Answer (score 19):

#### Preparation

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots( figsize=(15,6) )

Y1, Y2 = np.random.random((2,100))

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
```

#### Content

I'm surprised it did not show up so far but the simplest way is to either collect them manually into one of the axes objs (that lie on top of each other)

```py
l1 = ax1.plot( range(len(Y1)), Y1, label='Label 1' )
l2 = ax2.plot( range(len(Y2)), Y2, label='Label 2', color='orange' )

ax1.legend( handles=l1+l2 )
```

[image: Plot_axes]

or have them collected automatically into the surrounding figure by `fig.legend()` and fiddle around with the the `bbox_to_anchor` parameter:

```py
ax1.plot( range(len(Y1)), Y1, label='Label 1' )
ax2.plot( range(len(Y2)), Y2, label='Label 2', color='orange' )

fig.legend( bbox_to_anchor=(.97, .97) )
```

[image: Plot_figlegend]

#### Finalization

```py
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('stackoverflow.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Thank you for a really clear answer that works!

I additionally found that, if you are using `scatter` rather than `plot`, you need to do `handles=[l1+l2]` in the legend call due to them being `PathCollection` objects rather than simple lists.

Answer (score 9):

A quick hack that may suit your needs..

Take off the frame of the box and manually position the two legends next to each other. Something like this..

```
ax1.legend(loc = (.75,.1), frameon = False)
ax2.legend( loc = (.75, .05), frameon = False)
```

Where the loc tuple is left-to-right and bottom-to-top percentages that represent the location in the chart.

Answer (score 5):

I found an following official matplotlib example that uses host_subplot to display multiple y-axes and all the different labels in one legend. No workaround necessary. Best solution I found so far. 
http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

par1 = host.twinx()
par2 = host.twinx()

offset = 60
new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
par2.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right",
                                    axes=par2,
                                    offset=(offset, 0))

par2.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)

host.set_xlim(0, 2)
host.set_ylim(0, 2)

host.set_xlabel("Distance")
host.set_ylabel("Density")
par1.set_ylabel("Temperature")
par2.set_ylabel("Velocity")

p1, = host.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], label="Density")
p2, = par1.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 2], label="Temperature")
p3, = par2.plot([0, 1, 2], [50, 30, 15], label="Velocity")

par1.set_ylim(0, 4)
par2.set_ylim(1, 65)

host.legend()

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Focus on more current questions in the future, this one is nearly 4 years old.

Comment: Indeed a good find but I wish you would have taken what you learned from the example, applied it to the OP's MWE, and included an image.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Seaborn you can do this:

```
g = sns.barplot('arguments blah blah')
g2 = sns.lineplot('arguments blah blah')
h1,l1 = g.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2,l2 = g2.get_legend_handles_labels()
#Merging two legends
g.legend(h1+h2, l1+l2, title_fontsize='10')
#removes the second legend
g2.get_legend().remove()
```

Answer (score 2):

The solutions proposed so far have one or two inconvenients:

- Handles needs to be collected individually when plotting, e.g. `lns1 = ax.plot(time, Swdown, '-', label = 'Swdown')`. There is a risk of forgetting handles when updating the code.
- Legend is drawn for the whole figure, not by subplot, which is likely a no-go if you have multiple subplots.

This new solution takes advantage of [Axes.get_legend_handles_labels()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_legend_handles_labels.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_legend_handles_labels) to collect existing handles and labels for the main axis and for the twin axis.

**Collecting handles and labels automatically**

This numpy operation will scan all axes which share the same subplot area than `ax`, including `ax` and return merged handles and labels:

```
hl = np.hstack([axis.get_legend_handles_labels()
                for axis in ax.figure.axes
                if axis.bbox.bounds == ax.bbox.bounds])
```

It can be used to feed `legend()` arguments this way:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(1, 200)
signals = [np.exp(-t/20) * np.cos(t*k) for k in (1, 2)]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(10, 3), layout='constrained')
axes = axes.flatten()

for i, (ax, signal) in enumerate(zip(axes, signals)):
    # Plot as usual, no change to the code
    ax.plot(t, signal, label=f'plotted on axes[{i}]', c='C0', lw=9, alpha=0.3)
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    ax2.plot(t, signal, label=f'plotted on axes[{i}].twinx()', c='C1')

    # The only specificity of the code is when plotting the legend
    h, l = np.hstack([axis.get_legend_handles_labels()
                      for axis in ax.figure.axes
                      if axis.bbox.bounds == ax.bbox.bounds]).tolist()
    ax2.legend(handles=h, labels=l, loc='upper right')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As provided in the [example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html) from matplotlib.org, a clean way to implement a single legend from multiple axes is with plot handles:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

twin1 = ax.twinx()
twin2 = ax.twinx()

# Offset the right spine of twin2.  The ticks and label have already been
# placed on the right by twinx above.
twin2.spines.right.set_position(("axes", 1.2))

p1, = ax.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], "b-", label="Density")
p2, = twin1.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 2], "r-", label="Temperature")
p3, = twin2.plot([0, 1, 2], [50, 30, 15], "g-", label="Velocity")

ax.set_xlim(0, 2)
ax.set_ylim(0, 2)
twin1.set_ylim(0, 4)
twin2.set_ylim(1, 65)

ax.set_xlabel("Distance")
ax.set_ylabel("Density")
twin1.set_ylabel("Temperature")
twin2.set_ylabel("Velocity")

ax.yaxis.label.set_color(p1.get_color())
twin1.yaxis.label.set_color(p2.get_color())
twin2.yaxis.label.set_color(p3.get_color())

tkw = dict(size=4, width=1.5)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p1.get_color(), **tkw)
twin1.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p2.get_color(), **tkw)
twin2.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p3.get_color(), **tkw)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', **tkw)

ax.legend(handles=[p1, p2, p3])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc('mathtext', default='regular')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
pl_1, = ax.plot(time, Swdown, '-')
label_1 = 'Swdown'
pl_2, = ax.plot(time, Rn, '-')
label_2 = 'Rn'

ax2 = ax.twinx()
pl_3, = ax2.plot(time, temp, '-r')
label_3 = 'temp'

ax.legend([pl[enter image description here][1]_1, pl_2, pl_3], [label_1, label_2, label_3], loc=0)

ax.grid()
ax.set_xlabel("Time (h)")
ax.set_ylabel(r"Radiation ($MJ\,m^{-2}\,d^{-1}$)")
ax2.set_ylabel(r"Temperature ($^\circ$C)")
ax2.set_ylim(0, 35)
ax.set_ylim(-20,100)
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai0Bt.png)