# Multiple legends in for-loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

The following program executes fine but only one legend is displayed. How can I have all the four legends displayed? kindly see the image attached.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dct = {'list_1' : [1,2,4,3,1],'list_2' : [2,4,5,1,2],'list_3' : [1,1,3,4,6],'list_4' : [1,1,2,2,1]}

xs = [0,1,2,3,4]


for i in [1,2,3,4]:
    plt.plot(xs,dct['list_%s' %i])
    plt.legend(['%s data' %i])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: does only last legend gets displayed when you run this ??

Comment: I am assuming you really want one legend (that is the floating box) with all the entries in it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dct = {'list_1' : [1,2,4,3,1],'list_2' : [2,4,5,1,2],'list_3' : [1,1,3,4,6],'list_4' : [1,1,2,2,1]}

xs = [0,1,2,3,4]


for i in [1,2,3,4]:
    plt.plot(xs,dct['list_%s' %i], label='%s data' % i)

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

You are running up against the way that `legend` works, each time it is called it destroys the current legend and replaces it with the new one.  If you only give `legend` a list of strings it iterates through the artists (the objects that represent the data to be drawn) in the `axes` until it runs out of labels (hence why your first curve is labeled as the 4th).  If you include the `kwarg` `label` in the `plot` command, when you call `legend` with out any arguments, it will iterate through the artists* and generate legend entries for the artists with labels.

[*] there are some exceptions on which artists it will pick up

Answer (score 10):

AFAIK, you need to call legend once, with all the arguments.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dct = {'list_1' : [1,2,4,3,1],'list_2' : [2,4,5,1,2],
       'list_3' : [1,1,3,4,6],'list_4' : [1,1,2,2,1]}

xs = [0,1,2,3,4]

lines = []    
for i in range(1,5):
    lines += plt.plot(xs,dct['list_%s' %i], label="{} data".format(i))
```

Note that I have included the label here as one of the arguments to the plot function, so that later we can call  get_label().

```
labels = [l.get_label() for l in lines]
plt.legend(lines, labels)
plt.show()
```

This will also work if you have separate axes (such as twinx), and all of the legend information will come through on one legend. 
By the way, I seem to recall that the % notation is old and one should prefer str.format(), but I'm afraid I can't remember why.

Comment: you don't need to pull the labels out by hand, it will do that for you.  The `%` notation will be taken out of the language eventually but it has a huge install base (in the standard library no less) and will take a long time to expunge.

Comment: Indeed you are correct, I just happened to have it that way because I had multiple axes in that piece of code. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484922/secondary-axis-with-twinx-how-to-add-to-legend?rq=1) question. Thanks for reminding me about the %!