# Matplotlib: how to adjust zorder of second legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is an example that reproduces my problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data1,data2,data3,data4 = np.random.random(100),np.random.random(100),np.random.random(100),np.random.random(100)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(data1)
ax.plot(data2)
ax.plot(data3)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(data4)

plt.grid('on')
ax.legend(['1','2','3'], loc='center')
ax2.legend(['4'], loc=1)
```

[image]

How can I get the legend in the center to plot on top of the lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get exactly what you have asked for, try the following. Note I have modified your code to define the labels when you generate the plot and also the colors so you don't get a repeated blue line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data1,data2,data3,data4 = (np.random.random(100),
                           np.random.random(100),
                           np.random.random(100),
                           np.random.random(100))

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(data1, label="1", color="k")
ax.plot(data2, label="2", color="r")
ax.plot(data3, label="3", color="g")

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(data4, label="4", color="b")

# First get the handles and labels from the axes
handles1, labels1 = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()

# Add the first legend to the second axis so it displaysys 'on top'
first_legend = plt.legend(handles1, labels1, loc='center')
ax2.add_artist(first_legend)

# Add the second legend as usual
ax2.legend(handles2, labels2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Now I will add that it would be clearer if you just use a single legend adding all the lines to that. This is described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484922/secondary-axis-with-twinx-how-to-add-to-legend) and in the code above can easily be achieved with

```
ax2.legend(handles1+handles2, labels1+labels2)
```

But obviously you may have your own reasons for wanting two legends.

Comment: Ahh ok, that makes a lot of sense

Comment: For the incredulous among you... for those in awe... I can assure you--- it does work. I'm talking about the first approach with two legends. Search no more! You have found the answer.