# matplotlib twinx inside a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a loop which for a certain condition (occurs e.g 3 times), I'd like to plot two dataset with twinx, so e.g at the end I have 3 plots on left-y and 3 plots on right-y. When I use the usual twinx, the loop takes incorrect values for right-y. How should I modify this example code to get them correct? Thank you very much!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,10,100)
A=5

fig,ax=plt.subplots()

for i in range(0,10):
  A=i**2
  if(i%3==0):
    ax.plot(x,A*np.sin(x),'-ro')
    ax2=ax.twinx()
    ax2.plot(x,A*x,'-bp')
plt.show()
```

Here is the output.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your "ax2" definition outside the loop (see below).  However, this makes seven plots, four on left, three on right.  You need to update your "if" condition.

```
[![import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,10,100)
A=5

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax2=ax.twinx()

for i in range(0,10):
  A=i**2
  if(i%3==0):
    ax.plot(x,A*np.sin(x),'-ro')
    ax2.plot(x,A*x,'-bp')
plt.show()][1]][1]
```

[image: New figure, is this right?]

Comment: I am exactly in the same situation and I want to add legend. Can you add legend for each plot and display legend?

Comment: @JoonhoPark I think what you want is covered in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5487005/1678467