# Pandas Plot - Two Axis Labels Overlapping

Tags: python, plot

My code for graphing is as below:

```
ax30 = df5.plot(kind="scatter", x='Data Numbers', y='y', color="red", label="67890")
ax33 = ax30.twinx()
df8.plot(kind="scatter", x='Data Numbers', y='y', color="blue", label="12345", ax=ax33, secondary_y = True)

ax30.set_ylabel("A")
ax33.set_ylabel("B")
ax30.set_xlabel("C")
ax30.set_title("DDD")
ax30.set_xlim([0,150])
ax30.set_ylim([0,40000])
ax33.set_xlim([0,150])
ax33.set_ylim([0,40000])
```

I am trying to plot a data with two different y axis, but it seems like the legends are overlapping. How can I overcome this issue and put the legends back together?The current figure is as below:

Current resulting figure from the code

[image]

Comment: You defined your problem differently but I think this question will provide you with answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484922/secondary-axis-with-twinx-how-to-add-to-legend

Answer (score 0):

This solution should stack the labels vertically, removing any overlap:

```
ax30 = df5.plot(kind="scatter", x='Data Numbers', y='y', color="red", label="67890")
ax33 = df8.plot(kind="scatter", x='Data Numbers', y='y', color="blue", label="12345", ax=ax33, secondary_y = True)

plt.legend([ax30 , ax33], ['label_1', 'label_2'], loc=1)
```