# Only one dataname shows in the legend

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I like to display a diagram of two data columns. The problem about it is that the legend shows only the last name `l/s`.

Here is my diagram:

[image: Diagram]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Tab = pd.read_csv('Mst01.csv', delimiter=';')

x =  Tab['Nr. ']
y1 = Tab['cm']
y2 = Tab['l/s']

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

 ax2 = ax1.twinx()
 ax1.plot(x, y1, 'g-', label='cm')
 ax2.plot(x, y2, 'b-', label='l/s')

 ax1.set_xlabel('Nr.')
ax1.set_ylabel('cm', color='g')

ax2.set_ylabel('l/s', color='b')


plt.title('Mst01')

 plt.legend()

 plt.show()
```

If I do
     ax1.legend()
     ax2.legend()

both legends will displayed but one above the other.

By the way, is there a easyier way the get the spaces for every line of code?

Comment: ax2 doesn't know anything about ax1. This is one of the pitfalls of `twinx()`. You're probably best off just setting the legend of ax2 manually (e.g. `ax2.legend(['cm','l/s'])`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good evening!

so you got two possibilities either you add the plots together or you use `fig.legend()`

here is some sample code which yields to the solution

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create Example Dataframe
dummy_data = np.random.random_sample((100,2))
df = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data, columns=['Col_1', 'Col_2'])
df.Col_2 = df.Col_2*100

# Create Figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

col_1 = ax.plot(df.Col_1, label='Col_1', color='green')
ax_2 = ax.twinx()
col_2 = ax_2.plot(df.Col_2, label='Col_2', color='r')

# first solution
lns = col_1+col_2
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
ax.legend(lns, labs, loc='upper right')

# secound solution
fig.legend()
fig
```

The solution can be derived from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484922/secondary-axis-with-twinx-how-to-add-to-legend).

What do you mean by spaces? you mean the indention of e.g. a for loop?

Comment: Hey Moritz, Thank you very much, i choose the first solution and it works ! My question about the spaces is about stackoverflow, to get the codelabel you have to insert a space on every line of code. I tried the Tab to move the hole block but it wont work, maybe i have to use clips. Best regards Kai