# Issue with legend and x label

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, legend

I have almost a nice plot but there are  issues. The first one: x label doesn't show up. The second issue: I can't put the name of second line in legend. I have only one name (Close) and I need also 'KGHM'.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(x1,y1, 'y-')

myFmt = DateFormatter("%d-%m-%y")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.tight_layout()

plt.xlabel('PLN',size=10)
plt.ylabel('Points',size=10)
plt.title('KGHM')
ax.grid(True)

ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Thanks for help !

Comment: The reason for no xlabel is that you don't define any x label in your code. The second question has just been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332485/only-one-dataname-shows-in-the-legend) a few minutes ago.

Comment: Thank you for help with the second question. But as you can see a change xlabel in my cold and it's not working still

Comment: Yes, do it *before* defining the twin axes, or use object oriented style, `ax.set_xlabel("bla")` to set the label for the axes for which you want it.

Comment: I do it but it didn't help and I have the message: This figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight_layout, so results might be incorrect.
  warnings.warn("This figure includes Axes that are not compatible "

Comment: Perhaps there is a issue that there is not enough place... I don't know

Comment: ok, I got it. Thanks for help. In the end ax.set_xlabel("bla") did the work :)