# Plotting two data with greater difference

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, plotly

```
I have this data frame:
import pandas  as pd

In:


df= pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2007-01-01 07:14:00','2007-01-01 
07:25:00','2007-01-01 08:00:00','2007-01-01 09:14:00','2007-01-01 
09:33:12'],'sent':[-0.32,0.34,-0.45,0.7,0.22],'var1': 
[114,115,111,112,113],
'var2':[110,111,115,112,109]})

print(df) 
_____________________________________
out:

       Date             sent   var1 var2
0   2007-01-01 07:14:00 -0.32   114 110
1   2007-01-01 07:25:00 0.34    115 111
2   2007-01-01 08:00:00 -0.45   111 115
3   2007-01-01 09:14:00 0.70    112 112
4   2007-01-01 09:33:12 0.22    113 109
```

**Sample code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df.Date,df.sent,label='sent')
plt.plot(df.Date,df.var1,label='price1')
plt.plot(df.Date,df.var2,label= 'price2')
plt.show()
```

**Problem**

I want to plot line chart using above three columns but the problem is that column `sent`  has very small values as compared to other columns and when I add columns `sent` it's zoom out too much and the plot becomes nearly 3 straight lines that is not a good presentation of the data. However, with `var1` and `var2` only, plot is looking fine. Any suggestion would be highly appreciable. Thanks.

Primarily, I am using `plotly` to plot the data but I can also use matplotlib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a secondary y axis as following. First create an axis object `ax` and then plot directly using the DataFrame and use `secondary_y=True` for your `'sent'` column.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df= pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2007-01-01 07:14:00','2007-01-01 07:25:00','2007-01-01 08:00:00',
                      '2007-01-01 09:14:00','2007-01-01 09:33:12'],
              'sent':[-0.32,0.34,-0.45,0.7,0.22],'var1': [114,115,111,112,113],
              'var2':[110,111,115,112,109]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot('Date','var1',label='price1', ax=ax)
df.plot('Date','var2',label= 'price2',ax=ax)

df.plot('Date','sent',secondary_y=True, ax=ax, label='sent')
```

[image]

**Alternatively** you can also use explicitly `twinx` as following which generates the below figure. This is a bit tricky because now you will have two separate legend boxes. If you want to merge the two boxes together, you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484922/secondary-axis-with-twinx-how-to-add-to-legend) answer

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df.Date,df.var1,label='price1')
ax.plot(df.Date,df.var2,label= 'price2')
ax.legend(loc=0)

ax1 = ax.twinx()
ax1.plot(df.Date,df.sent,color='g', label='sent')
ax1.legend(loc=2)
```

[image]