# How to avoid overlapping legends when using two y-axes?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I was plotting two graphs and their legends are overlapping on top of another.
How can I put the legend for both 'Perfect' and 'Imperfect" without being overlapped?

```
plt.plot(wave_t, new_int_t, label='Perfect') #perfect
plt.ylabel("Relative Intensity")
plt.legend()

ax2 = plt.twinx()
ax2.plot(wave_t, int_t, c='C1', label='Imperfect')  #imperfect
ax2.set_ylabel("I(λ,T)")
ax2.legend()

plt.xlabel('Wavelength [nm]')
plt.title('Comparison of Lamp Spectrum')
```

[image]

Comment: you can try `ax2.legend(loc='upper left')`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Is there a way to put the legend together?

Comment: Yes! here: [Secondary axis with twinx(): how to add to legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484922/secondary-axis-with-twinx-how-to-add-to-legend)