# Legend picking breaks when drawing `plot`s instead of `scatter`s

Tags: python, matplotlib

Good day. This question is a follow-up of [Why does legend-picking only works for `ax.twinx()` and not `ax`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60167378/9282844).

The minimal code provided below plots two curves respectively on `ax1` and `ax2 = ax1.twinx()`, their legend boxes are created and the bottom legend is moved to the top ax so that picker events can be used. Clicking on a legend item will hide/show the associated curve.

If `ax.scatter(...)` is used that works fine. **If `ax.plot(...)` is used instead, legend picking suddenly breaks**. Why? Nothing else is changed so that's quite confusing. I have tested several other plotting methods and none of them work as expected.

Here is a video of it in action: https://imgur.com/qsPYHKc.mp4

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

X = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
Y1 = X**0.5 * np.sin(X)
Y2 = -np.cos(X)

# This is a quick way to change the plotting function, simply modify n.
n = 0
function, container = [("scatter", "collections"),
                       ("plot",    "lines"),
                       ("bar",     "patches"),
                       ("barbs",   "collections"),
                       ("quiver",  "collections")][n]
getattr(ax1, function)(X, Y1, color="green", label="$Y_1$")
getattr(ax2, function)(X, Y2, color="red",   label="$Y_2$")

# Put both legends on ax2 so that pick events also work for ax1's legend.
legend1 = ax1.legend(loc="upper left")
legend2 = ax2.legend(loc="upper right")
legend1.remove()
ax2.add_artist(legend1)

for n, legend in enumerate((legend1, legend2)):
    legend_item = legend.legendHandles[0]
    legend_item.set_gid(n+1)
    legend_item.set_picker(10)

# When a legend element is picked, hide/show the associated curve.   
def on_graph_pick_event(event):

    gid = event.artist.get_gid()
    print(f"Picked Y{gid}'s legend.")

    ax = {1: ax1, 2: ax2}[gid]
    for artist in getattr(ax, container):
        artist.set_visible(not artist.get_visible())
    plt.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("pick_event", on_graph_pick_event)
```

Comment: The solution in the linked question has been edited and now works beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I know this is not the answer, but the comments don't allow me to do this kind of brainstorming. I tried a couple of things, and noticed the following. When you print the `axes` of the `legendHandles` artists in your for loop, it returns `None` for both legends in the case of the scatter plot / `PathCollection` artists. However, in the case of the 'normal' plot / `Line2D` artists, it returns axes objects! And even more than that; even though in the terminal their representations seem to be the same (`AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)`), if you check if they are `== ax2`, for the `legendHandles` artist of `legend1` it returns `False`, while for the one of `legend2`, it returns `True`. What is happening here?

So I tried to not only remove `legend1` from `ax1` and add it again to `ax2` but to also do the same with the `legendHandles` object. But it doesn't allow me to do that:

```
NotImplementedError: cannot remove artist
```

To me it looks like you found a bug, or at least inconsistent behaviour. Here is the code of what I tried so far, in case anybody else would like to play around with it further.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import numpy as np

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

X = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
Y1 = X**0.5 * np.sin(X)
Y2 = -np.cos(X)

USE_LINES = True  # <--- set this to True or False to test both cases.
if USE_LINES:
    ax1.plot(X, Y1, color="green", label="$Y_1$")
    ax2.plot(X, Y2, color="red",   label="$Y_2$")
else:
    ax1.scatter(X, Y1, color="green", label="$Y_1$")
    ax2.scatter(X, Y2, color="red",   label="$Y_2$")

# Put both legends on ax2 so that pick events also work for ax1's legend.
legend1 = ax1.legend(loc="upper left")
legend2 = ax2.legend(loc="upper right")
legend1.remove()
ax2.add_artist(legend1)
# legend1.legendHandles[0].remove()
# ax2.add_artist(legend1.legendHandles[0])

for n, legend in enumerate((legend1, legend2)):
    legend_item = legend.legendHandles[0]
    legend_item.set_gid(n+1)
    legend_item.set_picker(10)
    print(
        f'USE_LINES = {USE_LINES}', f'legend{n+1}',
        legend_item.axes.__repr__() == legend.axes.__repr__(),
        legend_item.axes == legend.axes,
        legend_item.axes.__repr__() == ax2.__repr__(),
        legend_item.axes == ax2, type(legend_item),
    )

# When a legend element is picked, hide/show the associated curve.
def on_graph_pick_event(event):

    gid = event.artist.get_gid()
    print(f"Picked Y{gid}'s legend.")

    ax = {1: ax1, 2: ax2}[gid]
    artist = ax.lines[0] if USE_LINES else ax.collections[0]
    artist.set_visible(not artist.get_visible())
    plt.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("pick_event", on_graph_pick_event)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for trying! Another inconsistency if you check `legend.axes` and `legend_item.axes`: they both return `AxesSubplot(...)` when using scatters but return respectively `AxesSubplot(...)` and `None` when using plots.

Comment: Yeah, I find this super weird. I extended the print statement a little bit. Maybe this should me made into an issue for the mpl github.

Comment: Yep, I will have to do that eventually. The original post has been edited now to allow more functions to be tested quickly, and none of them works except `scatter`.