# Difficulty combining and repositioning the legends of two charts in matplotlib and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend

I am trying to plot two charts onto one figure, with both charts coming from the same dataframe, but one represented as a stacked bar chart and the other a simple line plot.

When I create the plot using the following code:

```
combined.iloc[:, 1:10].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(20,10))
combined.iloc[:, 0].plot(kind='line', secondary_y=True, use_index=False, linestyle='-', marker='o')
plt.legend(loc='upper left', fancybox=True, framealpha=1, shadow=True, borderpad=1)
plt.show()
```

With the `combined` data frame looking like this:

[image: source data frame]

I get the following image:

[image: stacked bar chart with line number of CVEs overlaid]

I am trying to combine both legends into one, and position the legend in the upper left hand corner so all the chart is visible.

Can someone explain why `plt.legend()` only seems to be editing the line chart corresponding to the `combined.iloc[:, 0]` slice of my `combined` dataframe? If anyone can see a quick and easy way to combine and reposition the legends please let me know! I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484922/secondary-axis-with-twinx-how-to-add-to-legend

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing `True` for the argument `secondary_y` means that the plot will be created on a separate axes instance with twin x-axis, since this creates a different axes instance the solution is generally to create the legend manually, as in the answers to the question [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484922/secondary-axis-with-twinx-how-to-add-to-legend) by [@ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest). If you don't want to create the legend directly you can get around this issue by calling `plt.legend()` between calls to `pandas.DataFrame.plot` and storing the result. You can then recover the handles and labels from the two axes instances. The following code is a complete example of this

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : np.random.random(25), 
                   'y' : np.random.random(25)*5, 
                   'z' : np.random.random(25)*2.5})

df.iloc[:, 1:10].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
leg = plt.legend()
df.iloc[:, 0].plot(kind='line', y='x', secondary_y=True)
leg2 = plt.legend()
plt.legend(leg.get_patches()+leg2.get_lines(), 
           [text.get_text() for text in leg.get_texts()+leg2.get_texts()], 
           loc='upper left', fancybox=True, framealpha=1, shadow=True, borderpad=1)
leg.remove()
plt.show()
```

This will produce

[image]

and should be fairly easy to modify to suit your specific use case.

Alternatively, you can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.figlegend()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figlegend.html), but you will need to pass `legend = False` in all calls to `pandas.DataFrame.plot()`, i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : np.random.random(25), 
                   'y' : np.random.random(25)*5, 
                   'z' : np.random.random(25)*2.5})

df.iloc[:, 1:10].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, legend=False)
df.iloc[:, 0].plot(kind='line', y='x', secondary_y=True, legend=False)

plt.figlegend(loc='upper left', fancybox=True, framealpha=1, shadow=True, borderpad=1)
plt.show()
```

This will however default to positioning the legend outside the axes, but you can override the automatic positioning via the `bbox_to_anchor` argument in calling `plt.figlegend()`.