# Python seaborn: Unable to make my chart look like excel chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a table like below, which is stored in pandas dataframe called 'data'.

| Column1 | Device1 | event_rate % | % event dist | % non-event dist | % total dist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Android | 3.08 | 27.3 | 32.96 | 32.75 |
| 1 | Chrome OS | 4.05 | 0.47 | 0.42 | 0.43 |
| 2 | Chromium OS | 9.95 | 0.23 | 0.08 | 0.09 |
| 3 | Linux | 2.27 | 0.05 | 0.09 | 0.09 |
| 4 | Mac OS | 6.43 | 4.39 | 2.45 | 2.52 |
| 5 | Others | 2.64 | 7.41 | 10.48 | 10.36 |
| 6 | Windows | 5.7 | 15.89 | 10.08 | 10.3 |
| 7 | iOS | 3.76 | 44.26 | 43.44 | 43.47 |

I am trying to create a desired seaborn/matplot chart like shown below which was created in excel.

[image]

Here is my python code:

```
feature = 'Device1'
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
color = 'tab:blue'
title = 'Event rate by ' + feature
ax1.set_title(title, fontsize=14)
ax1.set_xlabel(feature, fontsize=14)
ax2 = sns.barplot(x=feature, y='% non-event dist', data = data, color=color)
ax2 = sns.barplot(x=feature, y='% event dist', data = data, color='orange')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
ax1.set_ylabel('% Dist', fontsize=14, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
color = 'tab:red'
ax2.set_ylabel('Event Rate %', fontsize=14, color=color)
ax2 = sns.lineplot(x=feature, y='event_rate %', data = data, sort=False, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', color=color)
handles1, labels1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = handles1 + handles2
labels = labels1 + labels2
plt.legend(handles,labels)
plt.show()
```

Here is what I get

[image]

Issues:

1. Legend is not showing.
2. The barplots are overlapping each other.
3. Is there a way to show data labels?

How can I make my seaborn plot look similar to my excel plot? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Load & Shape DataFrame

- The most import part of plotting data is to correctly shape the DataFrame for the plot API.
- I think it is easier to convert the DataFrame from a wide to long format using `.stack`
- `.iloc[:, :-1]` selects all rows, but leaves the `'% total dist'` out.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# create dataframe
data = {'Device1': ['Android', 'Chrome OS', 'Chromium OS', 'Linux', 'Mac OS', 'Others', 'Windows', 'iOS'],
        'event_rate %': [3.08, 4.05, 9.95, 2.27, 6.43, 2.64, 5.7, 3.76],
        '% event dist': [27.3, 0.47, 0.23, 0.05, 4.39, 7.41, 15.89, 44.26],
        '% non-event dist': [32.96, 0.42, 0.08, 0.09, 2.45, 10.48, 10.08, 43.44],
        '% total dist': [32.75, 0.43, 0.09, 0.09, 2.52, 10.36, 10.3, 43.47]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df.head())
       Device1  event_rate %  % event dist  % non-event dist  % total dist
0      Android          3.08         27.30             32.96         32.75
1    Chrome OS          4.05          0.47              0.42          0.43
2  Chromium OS          9.95          0.23              0.08          0.09
3        Linux          2.27          0.05              0.09          0.09
4       Mac OS          6.43          4.39              2.45          2.52
```

```
# convert from a wide to long format
dfl = df.iloc[:, :-1].set_index('Device1').stack().reset_index(name='Values').rename({'level_1': 'Type'}, axis=1)

# select the desired data
dist = dfl[dfl.Type.str.contains('dist')]
rate = dfl[dfl.Type.str.contains('rate')]

# display(dist.head())
       Device1              Type  Values
1      Android      % event dist   27.30
2      Android  % non-event dist   32.96
4    Chrome OS      % event dist    0.47
5    Chrome OS  % non-event dist    0.42
7  Chromium OS      % event dist    0.23

# display(rate.head())
        Device1          Type  Values
0       Android  event_rate %    3.08
3     Chrome OS  event_rate %    4.05
6   Chromium OS  event_rate %    9.95
9         Linux  event_rate %    2.27
12       Mac OS  event_rate %    6.43
```

### Plot and Annotate

- I have place the legends next to their respective axes

  - See [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4700614/7758804) for additional options related to placing the legends.
- Referenced this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60352231/7758804) for creating the combined legend.
- Adjust the values in `bbox_to_anchor=(0.8, -0.25)` to move the legend around.

```py
# create the figure and primary axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 7))

# plot and format the bars
sns.barplot(data=dist, x='Device1', y='Values', hue='Type')
ax.set_ylabel('% Dist')
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
l1 = ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(-0.24, 1), loc='upper left')

# create the secondary axes
ax2 = ax.twinx()

# plot and format the line
sns.lineplot(data=rate, x='Device1', y='Values', ax=ax2, color='grey', label='event rate %', marker='o')
ax2.set_ylabel('% Event Rate')
l2 = ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 1), loc='upper left')

# combined legend by extracting the components from legend l1 and l2
plt.legend(l1.get_patches() + l2.get_lines(), 
           [text.get_text() for text in l1.get_texts() + l2.get_texts()], 
           bbox_to_anchor=(0.8, -0.25), ncol=3)

# remove l1 from the plot
l1.remove()

# annotate the line
for _, x, _, y in rate.itertuples():
    ax2.text(x, y, y)
```

### Combined Legend

[image]

### Separate Legend

- If you want separate legends, remove `plt.legend(...)` and `l1.remove()`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code and comments. I will surely give this a try.

Answer (score 2):

When using `sns.barplot()`, you can use `hue` parameter to make an unstacked bar chart, but you'll need an extra variable defining which variable to unstack (I'm using `pd.melt()` to deal with this).

For the legend, you can use `fig.legend()`.

To show data labels, use `plt.annotate()`

```
feature = 'Device1'
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
color = 'tab:blue'
title = 'Event rate by ' + feature
ax1.set_title(title, fontsize=14)
ax1.set_xlabel(feature, fontsize=14)
# ax2 = sns.barplot(x=feature, y='% non-event dist', data = data, color=color)
# ax2 = sns.barplot(x=feature, y='% event dist', data = data, color='orange')
ax1 = sns.barplot(x=feature, y='value', hue='variable', data=data.melt(['Device1'], ['% event dist', '% non-event dist']))
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
ax1.set_ylabel('% Dist', fontsize=14, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
color = 'tab:red'
ax2.set_ylabel('Event Rate %', fontsize=14, color=color)
# ax2 = sns.lineplot(x=feature, y='event_rate %', data = data, sort=False, color=color)
ax2 = sns.lineplot(x=feature, y='event_rate %', data = data, sort=False, color=color, label='event_rate %')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', color=color)
# handles1, labels1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
# handles2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
# handles = handles1[:-1] + handles2
# plt.legend(handles1, labels)
ax1.legend([])
ax2.legend([])
fig.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.75, -0.07), ncol=3)

# annotations
for x, y in enumerate(data['event_rate %']):
    plt.annotate(text=y, xy=(x-0.2,y+0.2))

## Use this for annotating if you want the annotations to go above and below the plot based on line direction
# prev_y = data['event_rate %'][0]
# for x, y in enumerate(data['event_rate %']):
#     plt.annotate(text=y, xy=(x-0.2,y+(0.2 if y >= prev_y else -0.2)))
#     prev_y = y

# set ylim to higher limit in order to accomodate the annotations    
ax2.set_ylim((0, 11))

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want a better looking grid, make sure that the values shown in yticks have the same length.

```
ax1.set_ylim(0,50) 
# ax1.get_yticks() -> [ 0. 10. 20. 30. 40. 50.] # length = 6
ax2.set_ylim((0, 11)) 
# ax2.get_yticks() -> [ 0.  2.  4.  6.  8. 10. 12.] # length = 7
yticks = np.linspace(0,11,len(ax1.get_yticks()))
ax2.set_yticks(yticks) 
# ax2.get_yticks() -> [ 0.   2.2  4.4  6.6  8.8 11. ] # length = 6
```

[image]

Or turn off the second axis grid, which will make the grid look similar to the excel chart.

```
ax2.grid(False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This looks great. :)