# How to draw a cumsum percent line-chart with a bar-chart?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to draw a bar chart and want to sum them with cumsum percent, but I don't know how to do.

**My sample code**
[image]

**I want the bellow plot**
[image]

Can someone know how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plot them on the same axis, you can do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y = np.array([115, 400, 200])
plt.bar(x, y)
ratio = y/y.sum()*100
cumsumRatio = ratio.cumsum()
ax.plot(x, cumsumRatio, color='orange')
for xy in zip(x, cumsumRatio):
    ax.annotate(f'({xy[1]:.2f}%)', xy=xy, textcoords='data')
```

[image]

Or on separate y axes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax  = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()


x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y = np.array([115, 400, 200])
ax.bar(x, y)
ratio = y/y.sum()*100
cumsumRatio = ratio.cumsum()
ax2.plot(x, cumsumRatio, color='orange')
for xy in zip(x, cumsumRatio):
    ax2.annotate(f'({xy[1]:.2f}%)', xy=xy, textcoords='data')
```

[image]

Comment: In `twinx` axis, how put line and bar `legend`  together?

Comment: see the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484922/secondary-axis-with-twinx-how-to-add-to-legend